# Auth0 NodeJS JWT authentication in API for mobile app

Tags: node.js, jwt, auth0

I'm a beginner in Auth0 and few days ago made iPhone app which use Auth0 login following the tutorial.
It was succeed so I could got `accessToken` and `idToken` successfully.
Just after that I tried to create nodejs server for API of that app with Auth0 jwt.
I followed the Auth0 tutorial this time too, and succeed to get 200 response with test access token from Auth0 API.

[image]

But my problem is when I request API on iPhone app with token, node server throw an exception.
If I send `accessToken` it throw `UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed`, and I found that the mobile `accessToken` has completely different format than the example `accessToken`.

```
UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed
    at /Volumes/Work/Work/NodeJS/GeoServer/GeoServer/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:102:22
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/Volumes/Work/Work/NodeJS/GeoServer/GeoServer/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:63:12)
    at verifyToken (/Volumes/Work/Work/NodeJS/GeoServer/GeoServer/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:100:13)
    at fn (/Volumes/Work/Work/NodeJS/GeoServer/GeoServer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
    at /Volumes/Work/Work/NodeJS/GeoServer/GeoServer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16
    at /Volumes/Work/Work/NodeJS/GeoServer/GeoServer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37
    at /Volumes/Work/Work/NodeJS/GeoServer/GeoServer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:706:43
    at /Volumes/Work/Work/NodeJS/GeoServer/GeoServer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Work/Work/NodeJS/GeoServer/GeoServer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1206:34)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
```

And if I send `idToken`, the `malformed` exception is gone, but I got another error in this time.

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
```

I'm working this part in several days but haven't found the solution yet.
Please give me any help to fix this issue.

Following is the node server codes.

```
import express from 'express';
import jwt from 'express-jwt';
import jwksRsa from 'jwks-rsa';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

const port = 3000

// Create middleware for checking the JWT
const jwtCheck = jwt({
    // Dynamically provide a signing key based on the kid in the header and the singing keys provided by the JWKS endpoint.
    secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json`
    }),

    // Validate the audience and the issuer.
    audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
    issuer: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}`,
    algorithms: ['RS256']
});
app.use(jwtCheck);

const locationHistory: any[] = [];

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.post('/api/location', (req, res) => {
    locationHistory.push({latitude: req.body.latitude, longitude: req.body.longitude});
    res.send(locationHistory);
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`API server is listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few days researching, finally I found the reason of issue.
There are two Applications - one is `Default Native` application and one is `MTM API` application. I was using the old Native application's `audience` in the iPhone app, that's why the two `accessTokens` are different format.
The `audience` is an identifier of each Auth0 application, so I should had paid attention on that.

[image]